# How to capture screenshot and share using Intent for BarChart Using PhilJay / MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android

I want to capture and share screenshots with other social media for BarChart in PhilJay / MPAndroidChart

```
        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                android:id="@+id/chart1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below code for taking screenshots of charts as a bitmap and share them with other social media apps without storing them in storage.

```
                Bitmap bitmap = mChart.getChartBitmap();
                String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "title", null);
                Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("image/jpg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```